# I am trying to execute an IF statement while executing a method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, while-loop

I am writing a watered down Blackjack game for my Ruby class, and I am hanging up after implementing my method for the hit or stay function. It isn't initiating the `while` statement below it. Hoping someone can tell me if the syntax is off or just an indentation error.

```ruby
def prompt_user()
  puts 'Would you like another card? Press y or n'
  hit_stay = gets.chomp
  while hit_stay == 'y' ||'n'
    if hit_stay == 'y'
      puts "Your cards are"
      puts $cards.append(num())
      puts "Your total card count is"
      puts $cards.sum
      return true
    elsif hit_stay == 'n'
      puts 'your total is'
      puts $cards.sum
      return true
    else
      puts ' This is not a valid option.'
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

This seems to be where the program gets wacky a little bit.

```ruby
prompt_user()
while prompt_user() == 'y' || 'n'
  $cards.sum <= 15
  prompt_user()
  if prompt_user() == 'n'
    puts 'Your final card count is.'
    puts $cards.sum
  end
  if 15 < $cards.sum <21
    puts 'Your final card count is.'
    puts $cards.sum
  elsif $cards.sum > 21
    puts 'Game Over You Bust'
  end
end
```

I am a little newer to writing code, I know I need to clean it up a bit but stressing out a little bit about this one.

Comment: Please, always try to tag your question with the programming language you're using. This way you'll attract more relevant people to your question and will not bother others, who have ignored some particular tags, or are not competent in the technology you're using.

Comment: opps sorry about that. I will make note for the future!

Comment: `==` has a higher [operator precedence](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) than `||`. Therefore, `while hit_stay == 'y' ||'n'` is equivalent to `while (hit_stay == 'y') || 'n'`. If `hit_stay #=> 'y'` we obtain `while true` (`'n'` is not examined). If `hit_stay` is any other value, `hit_stay == 'y' #=> false`, so the expression reduces to `while 'n'`. As `'n'` is *truthy* (i.e., neither `nil` nor `false`), this is equivalent to `while true` as well. Hence, one will never break out of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly answering your question but first off, `prompt_user() == 'y' || 'n'` is probably not what you're trying to do - this will always return true because it is saying "do this if the result of prompt_user() is equal to 'y', or if 'n'" however, 'n' itself is just a string not a condition and a non-empty string will evaluate to true so this will always be true no matter what the user's input is. To see what I mean, try doing `puts "hello!" if 'n'` and you'll see "hello!". What you probably want is `hit_stay == 'y' || hit_stay == 'n'` or even better `['y','n'].include?(hit_stay)`.

In your second part of the code, you're calling `prompt_user` all over the place and you're checking for the result of it to be equal to 'y' or 'n' but returning true/false in the actual method... I think what you're looking to do is just call prompt_user until it returns false in which case you'd want something closer to this:

```rb
while prompt_user
  $cards.sum <= 15
  if prompt_user() == 'n'
    puts 'Your final card count is.'
    puts $cards.sum
    if 15 < $cards.sum <21
      puts 'Your final card count is.'
      puts $cards.sum
    elsif $cards.sum > 21
      puts 'Game Over You Bust'
    end
  end
end
```

However, this code will still not work because `15 < $cards.sum < 21` is not valid ruby and should be `15 < $cards.sum && $cards.sum < 21`. Here's a more patched-up version of what you had, it still needs work to make it perfect (like exiting after you bust) but I'll leave that on you:

```rb
$cards = []
def num
  5
end

def prompt_user()
  puts 'Would you like another card? Press y or n'
  hit_stay = gets.chomp
  while ['y','n'].include?(hit_stay)
    if hit_stay == 'y'
      puts "Your cards are"
      puts $cards.append(num())
      puts "Your total card count is"
      puts $cards.sum
      return true
    elsif hit_stay == 'n'
      puts 'your total is'
      puts $cards.sum
      return true
    else
      puts ' This is not a valid option.'
      return false
    end
  end
end

while prompt_user
  $cards.sum <= 15
  puts 'Your final card count is.'
  puts $cards.sum
  if 15 < $cards.sum && $cards.sum < 21
    puts 'Your final card count is.'
    puts $cards.sum
  elsif $cards.sum > 21
    puts 'Game Over You Bust'
  end
end
```

PS. I'd also point out that using $ signs in variable names is not a typical ruby thing, you should just use alphanumeric characters. `@` is used for instance/class variables but that's presumably not what you're going for here.